# Why I get very huge output in printf on C language?

Tags: c

This is my code, I want to calculate distance between robot and monster, but the output "horizontal and vertikal" is false

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void findPos(char *dir, int a, int b)
{
    int up = 0, down = 0;
    int left = 0, right = 0;
    int i,x,y;

    for (i = 0; dir[i] != '\0' ; i++) {
        //Counts each direction
        if (dir[i] == 'U' || dir[i] == 'u')
            up++;
        else if (dir[i] == 'D' || dir[i] == 'd')
            down++;
        else if (dir[i] == 'L' || dir[i] == 'l')
            left++;
        else if (dir[i] == 'R' || dir[i] == 'r')
            right++;

          //In case of illegal character in the string
        else
        {
            printf("Position Unable to Find, Enter Correct Direction.");
            break;
        }
    }

    //Final position of robot
    x = right - left;
    y = up - down;

    printf("Final Position of the Robot: (");
    printf("%d", x);
    printf(",%d", y);
    print(")");

    printf("\nposition between robot and monster");
    printf("\nhorizontal: %d", a-x);
    printf("\nvertikal: %d", b-y);

}

int main()
{
    char *dir;
    int a,b,t;

    /* Intializes random number generator */
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));

    /* Print 2 random numbers from 0 to 100 */
    a = rand() % 100;
    b = rand() % 100;

    printf("\nCoordinate of monster: ");
    printf("(%d,", a);
    printf("%d)", b);
    //Input the direction string
    printf("\nEnter the Direction String: ");
    scanf("%s", &dir);
    //Function call to calculate position
    findPos(&dir, a,b);

    return 0;
}
```

and this is the output

```
Coordinate of monster: (5,47)  
Enter the Direction String: UURRRRRLLL
Final Position of the Robot: (2,2)  
position between robot and monster  
horizontal: 19530  
vertikal: 1280463440
```

Comment: Add printf statements to your code that examine the variables a, b, x and y.  Make sure those values are reasonable.

Comment: `dir` is a pointer that **NEVER** points to anywhere valid.

Comment: And even if dir pointed somewhere sensible, findPos is handed a pointer-to-a-pointer to it, which points to somewhere else entirely. (it's already char* , don't `&` it). This should normally generate at least some warnings, you **are** compiling with warnings enabled, right?

Comment: To clarify @pmg's comment, you want `char dir[2048]; scanf("%2047s", dir);` or similar.

Comment: s others have said: please enable warnings (usually `-Wall` or `/Wall`). Then fix these warnings: include `<stdlib.h>` for `srand` and `<time.h>` for `time`. You don't pass a pointer to the right type to `time`, better use `time(NULL)`.

Comment: So to address the core question "why did it print crazy stuff" - due to using an extra `&` in scanf and findpos, the direction characters were deposited on your stack and overwrote some other variables.

Comment: the pointer *dir need to malloc memory

Answer (score 1):

it seems your program is exhibiting undefined behavior, you are actually lucky its not crashing, `dir` is never allocated . you might want to `calloc` it before using , also remove the `&` in `scanf`, infact move to `fgets` unless inclined to use `scanf`

```
   printf("\nEnter the Direction String: ");
        scanf("%s", dir);
```